# Display few rows as columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not sure about how to write a query for this. While doing a few google stuff, I found solution is to use a pivot, but not sure how can it be applied for my tables.

I have 3 tables `TableDate`, `TableMembers` and `Sales`

I need to join 3 tables and get the below result.

My original query looks like

```
 SELECT [Member No], [Full Date],[Member State], SUM([Net Sales]) as Netsales
 FROM (([TableMembers]  inner join [TableDate]
 on [TableMembers].DateKey = [TableDate].DateKey)
 inner join [Sales]
 on [TableMembers].RID = [Sales].RID)
 where [Full Date] between '2014-01-01' and '2015-05-05'

 group by [Member No], [Full Date],[Member State]
 order by [Full Date]
```

Note: The first part is the original result, and the second part of image is my result. I also need to put a condition on date that only year `2013`, `2014` permitted.

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried? Show some effort!

Comment: Please include the details of your tables - what are the column names? What do we join the 3 tables on? And what do you want in the way of output? Sum for that date? Average for that date? Don't use images, please write out your tables and data so we can copy paste when we're writing our answers.

Answer (score 0):

For the sample, you can use following [SQL Pivot query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-pivot-tables-in-sql-server-tutorial-with-examples.aspx)

```
select
  *
from
(
  select
    member, date, state, net
  from tblSource
) SourceTable
PIVOT
(
  SUM(net)
  FOR date
  IN (
    [29-02-2013],[30-05-14]
  )
) PivotTable
```

But of course we have to enlarge the query for all dates
This requires building the above SQL pivot query as a dynamic SQL Pivot query
If you refer the referenced SQL tutorial, we can build it as follows

```
DECLARE @Dates VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Dates =
  COALESCE(
    @Dates + ',[' + cast([date] as varchar) + ']',
    '[' + cast([date] as varchar)+ ']'
  )
FROM tblSource

DECLARE @PivotSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotSQL = N'
select
  *
from
(
  select
    member, date, state, net
  from tblSource
) SourceTable
PIVOT
(
  SUM(net)
  FOR date
  IN (
' + @Dates + '
    )
  ) AS PivotTable
'

EXECUTE(@PivotSQL)
```

Output is as follows

[image]

Comment: Hi Eralper, thanks but what if I want a range of dates like all dates between 2013 to 2015?

Comment: Yes sure because of that reason, you need to use a dynamic SQL query. The output is for two dates since I have only two rows. Any additional date will show up as a new column in the output of the second SQL Select query with Pivot